Minimal web browser with system shortcuts
I'm looking for a Linux browser that can be minimally intrusive and dedicate everything to the system interface. I am not as pretentious as I was before: I have two requirements.

It should be minimal, one-line interface. It may or may not have tab support. Min and Colibri are good examples
It should be able to create shortcuts for websites and open them in separate windows with their own icons. Chrome can do this:


